# asp.net role based authorization with wildcard names

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to implement the role based authorization in .net core web api. I don't have the fixed role names. I have to validate with the common prefix only. For example, in JWT claim the role will be as below.

```
"roles": [
    "Approver@UK",
    "Approver@US",
    "Approver@DE",
......
  ]
```

If the user has approver prefix in the claim, i would allow them to access the api. 
I don't want to add "Approver" as a separate role and i cannot put all the roles in the attribute. I am trying the below syntax, but no luck.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Approver@*")]
```

How can i verify the role by prefix or kind of like condition, rather than the full role name.

Comment: You may need to create your own custom Authorization Attribute.. deriving from the system one. Just in case you're using ASP.NET Core, policy based authorization would be better.

Comment: I am using .net core only, will try that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The example can be found under for dynamic authorization policies.

https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/tree/master/samples/CustomPolicyProvider

Comment: This is a link to an answer, as opposed to an answer.